# Multiple where conditions with several different cases

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, logic

I have an issue I just cant get my head around, like logically.

Here is the situation:

I have an user who an submit an application, said application can either be:

1. Canceled by the user
2. canceled by the company
3. accepted by the company

Now to avoid someone submitting an application for a job multiple times I need to check if either of those values are true, here is my migration for an application:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('bewerbungens', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('Bewerbung_ID');
            $table->string('bewerber_email');
            $table->bigInteger('Stellenanzeigen_ID');
            $table->boolean('is_Accepted')->default(false);
            $table->date('accept_Date')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('is_Canceled')->default(false);
            $table->date('cancel_Date')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('is_Canceled_Bewerber')->default(false);
            $table->date('cancel_Date_Bewerber')->nullable();
        });
    }
```

Now in my Controller where I handle the submission of an application I first check if the user has an active application & I check the values of those three columns with this query:

```
$tmp = DB::table('bewerbungens')
            ->where('bewerber_email', $request->email)
            ->where('Stellenanzeigen_ID', $request->Stellenanzeigen_ID)
            ->where('is_Canceled_Bewerber', '=', false)
            ->orWhere('is_Accepted', '=', false)
            ->orWhere('is_Canceled', '=', false)
            ->count();
```

So the first part is to check IF there is an application by this user to this particular job posting. However I just don't get how I need to check if one of those values is true.

I thought about making a separate query for each column and then check them in an if statement, like so:

```
$tmp = DB::table('bewerbungens')
            ->where('bewerber_email', $request->email)
            ->where('Stellenanzeigen_ID', $request->Stellenanzeigen_ID)
            ->count();

        $tmp1 = DB::table('bewerbungens')
            ->where('bewerber_email', $request->email)
            ->where('Stellenanzeigen_ID', $request->Stellenanzeigen_ID)
            ->get('is_Canceled_Bewerber');

        $tmp2 = DB::table('bewerbungens')
            ->where('bewerber_email', $request->email)
            ->where('Stellenanzeigen_ID', $request->Stellenanzeigen_ID)
            ->get('is_Accepted');

        $tmp3 = DB::table('bewerbungens')
            ->where('bewerber_email', $request->email)
            ->where('Stellenanzeigen_ID', $request->Stellenanzeigen_ID)
            ->get('is_Canceled');
        $a = $tmp1[0]->is_Canceled_Bewerber;
        $b = $tmp2[0]->is_Accepted;
        $c = $tmp3[0]->is_Canceled;

        if ($tmp != 0 && isFalse($a) && isFalse($b) && isFalse($c)) {
            ....
        }
```

I am thankful for any input because I feel so dumb right now and have like a huge blockage in my head.

Comment: can they post to the same job more than once, regardless of the state of those fields? if they closed the application can they submit a new one to the same job?

Comment: Yeah if the themselves close the application they can re-apply!

Comment: Ah sorry, as soon as they are accepted or rejected by the company they cant apply anymore. so when `is_Canceled` or `is_Accepted` are true. they can just re-apply when `is_Canceled_Bewerber` is true in an existing application

Comment: just a suggestion: use a status column instead of is_Canceled, is_Accepted multiple columns

Comment: @Garry yeah would be the best and cleanest solution! But I am not allowed to, it is for uni and we had to give our final DB design before starting programming and if I change something now it impacts my grade negatively since they say our planning was bad when we need to change something :/

Comment: @newbie oh. did you find the answer you looking for?

Comment: @Garry yeah i solved it with spaghetti code, I just check every column individually in an if statement and redirect back with an error when the if statement is true. So not the best solution but it works for now :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, user can't apply if they already applied. Doesn't matter if its accepted or canceled right?

So you can check if record exist on table if so you wont let user apply again

```
    $tmp = DB::table('bewerbungens')
        ->where('bewerber_email', $request->email)
        ->where('Stellenanzeigen_ID', $request->Stellenanzeigen_ID)
        ->count();
```

Comment: Correct, but they can cancel their application and re-apply

Comment: But the application exists "forever" - they don't get deleted, just the boolean values of is_Canceled etc are changed accordingly

Comment: Can you just add new column to table called "can_apply" and handle these rules in controller, like if they cancel their application set can_apply true or if company cancel that application set to false. Whenever user apply an application just check if is there any match with ids and all of them has can_apply true.

Comment: yeah that would be the best solution, and I forgot to write it in the question. I am not allowed to, it is for a university project and we had to hand in our database design beforehand and are not allowed to change something. Or we can change something, but it impacts the grade because we planned "bad" if we need to change something

Comment: you can create new migration by php artisan make:migration  add_can_apply_column_to_bewerbunges_table  --table="bewerbunges" .Add "can_apply" column in that table , so they dont think you planned something bad but you improving project

Comment: yeah I know that, but they have my Database Model with all columns, so they can check if there is a column more in the end :/ bit dumb of a rule but it is what it is. Appreciate the answer tho!